# Undefined values handling: Proxy vs raw boolean

Tags: javascript, proxy

I'm confused to specify a way to handle undefined values in my new project.
Recently, I ran into with the proxy concept what allowed me to do the following:

```
const handler = { get: (obj, prop) => (prop in  obj ? obj[prop] : 210)};
const p = new Proxy({'80mm' : 80, '210mm': 210}, handler);

console.log('50mm' in p, p.c)
// false, 210
```

In the other hand, it could simply be:

```
const options = {'80mm' : 80, '210mm': 210 };

console.log(options['50mm'] || 210)
// 210
```

Which one would be the best choice?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "raw boolean"?

Comment: Hello there!
I'm so sorry, maybe my sentence was not clear enough. 
For this case, it was a simple mention to highlight  || and &&.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` logical operator is much, much cheaper than a proxy. It also is much more idiomatic. You'd only need a proxy if you couldn't control the code that access the property.

I would however suggest a third alternative: explicitly writing out

```
console.log('50mm' in options ? options['50mm'] : 210)
// or
console.log(typeof options['50mm'] == "number" ? options['50mm'] : 210)
```

which would work even when the `options` object contained a falsy value (`0`) or the key is something weird like `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Thank you! Your tip was clarifying for me.